# Java "Interface" class

Tags: java, class, interface, java-8

In Java, there is a [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) class that can be used to represent other classes without instantiating them. For example:

```
Class[] foo = { ArrayList.class, String.class, Character.class, Integer.class, MyCustomClass.class };
ArrayList bar = foo[0].newInstance();
```

would be valid code. I could also, for example, run through an array of `Object`s and do `instanceof` checks on all of them to the corresponding classes in the `foo` array, which has potential applications.

Does such a class exist in Java for [interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(Java))? Is there some class for which I can do something resembling this:

```
Interface[] foo = {Comparable, List<String>, MyCustomInterface}
```

Since as of Java 8, Interfaces can now have static methods, this behavior could be useful, if bad practice. Does it exist?

Comment: You mean `ArrayList.class, String.class` etc, right?

Comment: [*Instances of the class `Class` represent classes **and interfaces** in a running Java application.*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An interface is just a class for which [`Class.isInterface()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInterface()) returns true. So:

```
Class<?>[] foo = {Comparable.class, List.class, MyCustomInterface.class};
```

Note that there is no generic class instance for, e.g. `List<String>`: it's just raw `List.class`.

Comment: I wonder if you could declare an Interface class which extends Class to get the OP's behavior?  (Not that it's a good idea, just curious if it's possible!)

Comment: @DanielWiddis given that `Class` is `final`, no, it is not possible.